# Migrate Windows Service to Azure

Tags: azure

We are migrating to Azure. We have a Web App deployed. However, I have a Windows Service that I need to add in to the mix.  The service continuously runs, checking the associated Service Bus Queue for messages every 5 seconds.

I am looking for recommendations on how to do this.

I have looked at Web Jobs.  But, I don't understand how it gets kicked off.  I know there is a Web Hook involved - but I just want the code to run continuously without having to be constantly kicked.

We are also trying to avoid the cost of having a VM involved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create Webjobs can be triggered or run continuously. The triggering can either be with an api call, or on a timetable using a cron expression. Sounds like you want continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a web app, you could use a Azure App Service to run the Web App. The Azure App Service will allow you to also have a Web Job that you can have run on a schedule.

It does not make sense to break you web app into Azure Functions since it is already built. You can have the service run in an Azure Function, but it will probably add more complexity to interact with the web app (if that is what is happening) and if the service is running every 5 seconds, that could get costly.